# How to code a float list ModelSerializer for DRF a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

## TL; DR

How to create both `serializers.Patient` and `serializers.Temperature` in such way that:

1. `models.Patient` has one-to-many relationship with `models.Temperatures`
2. `serializers.Patient` is a subclass of `serializers.ModelSerializer`
3. `serializers.Patient` (de)serialize temperatures as a list of floats

## Details

Given a **quick-dirty** patient medical records RESTful API implemented with [Django framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Patient is defined at `models.Patient` as:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    updated_at = models.DateField()
```

and the `models.Temperature`:

```
class Temperature(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField()
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        db_column='patient',
        related_name='temperatures',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    updated_at = models.DateField()
    value = models.FloatField()
```

CRUD operations at `/patients` (de)serialized `models.Temperature` as `float` lists, thus a `POST` should only require:

```
{
  "name": "John Connor",
  "temperatures": [36.7, 40, 35.9]
}
```

while a `GET` operation

```
{
  "created_at": "1985-03-25",
  "name": "John Connor",
  "temperatures": [36.7, 40, 35.9],
  "updated_at": "2021-08-29"
}
```

**However** operations at `/patients/<id>/temperatures/` endpoint should return **all properties**:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "1985-03-25",
    "value": 36.7,
    "updated_at": "2021-08-29"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "1985-03-25",
    "value": 40.0,
    "updated_at": "2021-08-29"
  },
  {
    "created_at": "1985-03-25",
    "value": 35.9,
    "updated_at": "2021-08-29"
  }
]
```

Can this feature be implemented subclassing standards [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) serializers or does it require a customized `serializers.Serializer` subclass?

Comment: I think your `Temperature` model is missing the attribute `value`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's try to analyze the situation here. We need to input the temperature data with a list. So, let's use `ListField` for this purpose. So, we should start like this:

```
class PatientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    temperatures = ListField(child=FloatField())
```

What this will do is expect a list of floats from the user.
But how will we get the array of the temperatures of the created patient when using `GET` operation. For this, let's add a source to the field. Whatever is  written on the `source` param will get converted into the `patient.field` for example:

```
class PatientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    temperatures = ListField(child=FloatField(), source="temperature_list")
```

This `source="temperature_list` will user `patient.temperature_list` and show the result when serializing the object. Now let's add some property to the original model so that we can get the clean temperature array like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    updated_at = models.DateField()

    @property
    def temperature_list(self):
        return [temperature.value for temperature in self.temperatures.all()]
```

We are almost done. Now we need to override the `create` method for `PatientSerializer` so that it can save the temperatures present in the list.
Now, to get the temperature data from the `validated_data` we need to use the same field that is used in the `source` argument on the `ListField`, which is `temperature_list`. So, we need to pop this data, create the user, validate the temperature list items, create temperature objects that are related to the patient. Let's create a `TemperatureSerializer` like this:

```
class TemperatureSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Temperature
        fields = ("created_at", "value", "updated_at", "patient")
        extra_kwargs = {
            "patient": {"write_only": True},
            "created_at": {"required": False},
            "updated_at": {"required": False},
        }
```

Now, all we need to do is, write the create method. We can write it like this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    temperatures = validated_data.pop("temperature_list")
    now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    patient = Patient.objects.create(
        created_at=now, updated_at=now, **validated_data
    )
    for temperature in temperatures:
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        temperature_serializer = TemperatureSerializer(
            data={
                "value": temperature,
                "created_at": now,
                "updated_at": now,
                "patient": patient.id,
            }
        )
        temperature_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        temperature_serializer.save()
    return patient
```

Finally, let's put together all the things and this is how the `serializers.py` file would look like:

```
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, ListField, FloatField
from datetime import datetime

from .models import Patient, Temperature


class TemperatureSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Temperature
        fields = ("created_at", "value", "updated_at", "patient")
        extra_kwargs = {
            "patient": {"write_only": True},
            "created_at": {"required": False},
            "updated_at": {"required": False},
        }


class PatientSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    temperatures = ListField(child=FloatField(), source="temperature_list")

    def create(self, validated_data):
        temperatures = validated_data.pop("temperature_list")
        now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        patient = Patient.objects.create(
            created_at=now, updated_at=now, **validated_data
        )
        for temperature in temperatures:
            now = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            temperature_serializer = TemperatureSerializer(
                data={
                    "value": temperature,
                    "created_at": now,
                    "updated_at": now,
                    "patient": patient.id,
                }
            )
            temperature_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            temperature_serializer.save()
        return patient

    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ("created_at", "name", "temperatures", "updated_at")
        extra_kwargs = {
            "created_at": {"required": False},
            "updated_at": {"required": False},
        }
```

This is how the `views.py` would look like:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListCreateAPIView, ListAPIView

from .models import Patient, Temperature
from .serializers import PatientSerializer, TemperatureSerializer

class PatientListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PatientSerializer
    queryset = Patient.objects.all()


class TemperatureListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TemperatureSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        patient_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
        return Temperature.objects.filter(patient_id=patient_id)
```

And the `urls.py` file:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("patients", views.PatientListCreateView.as_view(), name="patient-list"),
    path(
        "patients/<int:pk>/temperatures/",
        views.TemperatureListView.as_view(),
        name="patient-temperature-list",
    ),
]
```

This is how the `POST` method would work:
[image]

And this is how the temperatures of a patient would return:
[image]

I hope this answers your questions.